# Validate the syntax of PHP files more efficiently

Tags: php, continuous-integration, syntax

**Validating the syntax of a bunch of PHP files is SLOW**

We use `php -l file.php` to validate the syntax of many php files as part of a continuous integration setup.  We actually do something like: `find . -name "*.php" | xargs --max-args=1 php -l" because the **php executable only takes one argument**.

This is *horrendously slow* and mostly because it involves firing up a brand new parser / interpreter (not to mention process) for each PHP file in order to verify it's syntax and we have thousands.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Do you really need to re-validate every php file every time?  Con't you add an `-mtime n` to your find so it only validates stuff recently updated?

Comment: I would consider this more of a topic for [SO], but my first idea is to check if you can use something like PHP-FPM for your advantage, also the question remains if you always have to check everything.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601031/is-there-a-good-robust-php-lint-or-code-quality-tool

Comment: Even better is to make a pre-commit hook in your version control (Git / Subversion) that checks the file syntax before allowing to commit it. (SVN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606385/svn-post-pre-commit-hook-to-check-php-syntax-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding a time in the search eg

```
`find . -mtime -7 -name "*.php" | xargs --max-args=1 php -l
```

to the find command to only validate the files that have been modified on the last week?

I am presuming most of your code base does not change every few days?

**Updated**

You might also want to try the -newer flag

```
`find . -newer /path/to/file -name "*.php" | xargs --max-args=1 php -l
```

it finds all files newer than the one given, very handy, especially if your version control changes a certain system file every time you checkout alternatively use:

```
touch -t 201303121000 /path/to/file
```

to create a dummy file for use with -newer

Comment: This is a great solution. Git doesn't version-control modified dates, so running a `git checkout branch` will touch every file modified in that branch. This allows an even smaller time-frame and thus even fewer files to check.

Answer (score 1):

I've given up on `php -l` entirely for the same reason, though in my case (and perhaps in yours) it doesn't matter.

Since I'm using PHPUnit for my unit tests I don't need to lint the files being tested. If the file wouldn't pass the linter it won't pass any tests either (even one which simply includes the file).

If you *haven't* covered 100% of your files with PHPUnit, you may be able to fake the effect of the linter with something like:

```php
class FakeLinterTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testLintAllTheFiles() {
        foreach ($this->listAllPHPFiles() as $file) {
            include_once($file);
        }
    }

    private function listAllPHPFiles() {
        // Traverse your entire source tree.
    }
}
```

That code is entirely untested. Also, if you have a big project you may need to play games with memory limits and/or break up the "lint" into chunks to stop it murdering your CI system.

Comment: Blindly executing all PHP files with include_once() doesn't quite seem like a foolproof solution, since that in itself could trigger exceptions in those files - exceptions that are not related to syntax...